# Sending push notification to iphone using ejabberd xmpp

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, ejabberd

I am using **ejabberd** with **xmpp** protocol. need to send push notifications to ios. I am using **mod_apns** module of ejabberd.

```
Creating ssl connection with apns
sendpush() ->
Address = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",
  Port = 2195,
  Cert = "cert.pem",
  Key = "key-noenc.pem",  
  %Options = [{cacertfile, CaCert}, {certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Key}, {mode, binary}],
  Options = [{certfile, Cert}, {keyfile, Key}, {mode, binary}],
  Timeout = 1000,
  {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect(Address, Port, Options, Timeout),
```

I am getting error {Options,{mode, binary}}
can someone help me to create connection of apns ssl.

Comment: Which mod_apns are you using ? There is no such module included as default in ejabberd.

Comment: i am following this [link](https://github.com/mrDoctorWho/ejabberd_mod_apns)  that is not default module of ejabberd -@MickaëlRémond

Comment: Can you show the exact error from the log ? Your post is too limited for now for someone to give you meaningful advices.